# How to subtract vectors in $3$D

Tags: vectors

How do I subtract vectors in $3$D when they are written like this:

$$A=1i+2j+3k$$
$$B=3i+2j+1k$$

(Just an example)

Comment: Subtract componentwise.

Comment: In this case you don't even have to care if it's a vector. Whatever i,j,k are, the algebra is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$A=a_1i+a_2j+a_3k\quad\text{and}\quad B=b_1i+b_2j+b_3k,$$
then
$$A-B=(a_1-b_1)i+(a_2-b_2)j+(a_3-b_3)k.$$
Thus, in your case
$$A-B=(1-3)i+(2-2)j+(3-1)k=-2i+2k.$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$AB=OB-OA=3i+2j+k-(i+2j+3k)=2i-2k$$

Answer (score 0):

$i, j, k$ are just names for the three canonical unit vectors $e_i$.

You can write the vectors as tuples $A = (1,2,3)^\top$ and $B = (3,2,1)^\top$ and subtract component-wise.
$$
A - B = (1 - 3, 2 - 2, 3 - 1)^\top = (-2,0,2)^\top = -2 i + 0 j + 2k = -2i + 2k
$$